# Issue: bash: /home/abdulqadir/.bashrc: line 116: syntax error near unexpected token `export'

Tags: bash

After pasting the text at the end of bashrc file I'm having this issue. Please help me in this.

```
bash: /home/abdulqadir/.bashrc: line 116: syntax error near unexpected token `export'
bash: /home/abdulqadir/.bashrc: line 116: `  fi export ROOTSYS=/home/abdulqadir/root'
```

Comment: Seems that in line 116 of `/home/abdulqadir/.bashrc` there is a missing new line between `fi` and `export`. Please [edit] your question adding the content of `/home/abdulqadir/.bashrc` file

Comment: Or supply a semicolon ("`;`") between `fi` and `export-`.Always paste your `.bashrc` into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.